# Copying a database in Progress 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am Using AppBuilder.In that if I am trying to connect to Sports2000 database.Even though there is a option to create a database its prompting to copy a database.Can I know the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an app-builder user but I would imagine that it is creating a new db by copying an existing db.  The standard candidates would be "sports", "sports2000" or "empty".

Answer (score 0):

You can connect a database from the AppBuilder using Tools -> Database connections -> Connect.

---

You cannot connect to databases in the OpenEdge installation directory. These are only used as templates to create new databases.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new DB, you have option to start with:

- Empty - to create a new empty DB
- Copy from - copy DB Schema from other DB, such as sports, sports2000 or other existing DB.